# Can't connect to TCP port on Android

Tags: c#, android, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an Android app (really Xamarin app) and I'm using Socket to listen on port 8888 on the **Android** app.
So, I want to connect to this port from another computer by tcp (from PC TO Android).

And, I receive the following error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
error 10061
```

My code (I got it from MS examples) works for two console apps. But if Android is server it doesn't work.

I try ping phone from pc, and it is OK.

**My question: maybe should open a port? Or something else? How can I do this?**

I will gladly to listen any ideas. Thanks.

My server code. C#, Xamarin.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Android.Runtime;
using Java.Lang;
using Byte = System.Byte;
using Exception = System.Exception;
using String = System.String;
using StringBuilder = System.Text.StringBuilder;

// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    // Thread signal.
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {
    }

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 });
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8888);
        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(remoteEP);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);



                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the 
                // client. Display it on the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                    content.Length, content);
                // Echo the data back to the client.
                Send(handler, content);

            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

My client code. Just simple C# console app:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class SynchronousSocketClient
{

    public static void StartClient() {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        Console.WriteLine("Start!");

        // Connect to a remote device.
        try {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            // This example uses port 11000 on the local computer.


           IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 10, 0, 1, 173 });
         //   IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 });
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8888);

            // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
            try {
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                    sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Encode the data string into a byte array.
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");

                // Send the data through the socket.
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                // Receive the response from the remote device.
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec));

                // Release the socket.
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();

            } catch (ArgumentNullException ane) {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}",ane.ToString());
            } catch (SocketException se) {

                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}",se.ErrorCode);
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}",se.SocketErrorCode);
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}",se.ToString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine( e.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Almost certainly a networking config error.  If your android device is on cellular it will never work-  cellular networks don't allow the requests through.  If your device is on wifi you'll need to make sure your router allows the request through.

Comment: Yes, i use wifi. Thanks, i'll check!

Comment: `IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 });` It makes no sense to listen on 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate scenarios for socket-based data transport (in a typical local lan setting where there is an ordinary isp router in place):

1. Any client app (including browser) that connects to a well-known server endpoint (specific ip address and port) and just connects to establish a tcp session, and never listens.  This is no problem.  The router allows allows outgoing connection attempts.
2. Any client app that wants to connect to another client app that is listening.  This is more difficult in that the router in a local lan setting does not typically allow any incoming connection attempts to a local host.  Further the router is probably doing NAT translation so it has an addressable internet-facing ip address and has configured a specific external port to route to a specific internal host machine that is presumably listening at a local address and port.

There are several ways to determine what this endpoint addressing mapping configuration is but none of them are very convenient.  The key point is that the router will only open an internal host to communications from the external internet if that host has previously tried to tcp connect to that external host (whether it be a server or a peer client app).  This works for the browser/website server configuration because the client is always doing the connecting so the router opens the communication channel for that specific addressed external server and allows incoming data to be received by the client (browser).  It is a similar situation for udp data transport.  The router will only open the internal host to external incoming udp data if the internal client has recently sent a message to that specific peer.  Http (a Tcp variant) provides the client/server protocol that uses this router convention for browser/website connectivity and communications.  But for the peer client that wants to act as both a client and a server, there are significant barriers.  Of course local lan socket communications are no problem, as local ip addresses are available for any internal lan peer.